# Run .sql file with PSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a .sql file that has several commands in it like this:

```
alter table mytable add codecolumn varchar(10);
update mytable set codecolumn = 'code';
alter table mytable set anothercolumn = 'anothervalue';
```

This is a PostgreSQL database and I'm trying to use psql to execute the file like so:

```
psql -h hostname -d dbname -w -f "C:\filepath\filename.sql"
```

The problem I'm noticing is that it's not executing the commands in the same order as it would if I opened up a query window and ran it that way - from top to bottom. I know this because it's saying that `codecolumn` doesn't exist.

My goal is to turn this into a batch file to run periodically without having to open up the database. Is there a better way to run this or tell it to run the commands in order?

specs: PostgreSQL 9.5.1, Windows 10 64 bit

UPDATE:
I noticed this strange character is being added to the beginning of the first statement:

```
LINE 1: ï»¿alter table "mytable" add codecolumn varchar (10);
```

I believe it's skipping this initial statement as a result.

Comment: `psql` will most definitely process the SQL statements in that file from top to bottom.

Comment: it's weird because when I open it up and run it with the query window it executes fine, but then when I try to run it via psql it tells me the column is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to this here:

https://www.postgresql-archive.org/Using-psql-f-to-load-a-UTF8-file-td5724735.html

The solution was to add an additional line to the file with a semicolon so that the encoding error get tripped up on that.